# Is there a limit of text data that can be stored in an executable binary?

Tags: objective-c, c, sqlite, mach-o, darwin

My OS X app features an in-application help system that consists of static strings worth roughly 4 MB of raw text data.

Normally, one would store these help texts in and on access fetch them from a lightweight database (SQLite springs to mind) that comes bundled with the application binary. Instead, for the reason of simplicity I chose to store the help text in a large `NSDictionary` consisting of many `NSString` (generated automatically at compile time). Access is reasonably fast and the only "drawback" I can think of is the constant consumption of 4 MB of memory the `NSDictionary` has even when it's not in use - which is really not an issue with modern day hardware.
My solution is pragmatic, works fine for now, makes a compact app that doesn't spill its internal data on disk and yet it gives me an uneasy feeling.

So, I think my question is if what I'm doing is okay or if it is bad practice in any way.  Concise:
**Is it, from a technical point of view, okay to "bake in" large amounts of text into an application binary?**
Is there a size limit of static variable data that can be stored in (64 bit) Darwin Mach-O images?

Comment: ISTM that the resources of many APP "files" are much larger than 4 MB, so I would not worry too much. Do what is practical, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

and when you find a typografically error, you have to compile the app and deploy it entirely, instead of just provide an update to the database. This makes the deployment for the customer more smoothly.

And when it happens, that your app is so demanded, that you want to provide a (f.e.) german language version, you have to change everything from scratch.

as a rule of thump: small binary, large database, assets separately.

Comment: These are valid points but not true for my situation: It is an app on the Mac App Store so each modification, no matter how small, must go through the whole deployment process anyway. Also, my text data already is translated dynamically into Objective-C code by a script, so support for new languages would be trivial. I guess I should rephrase my question: Are there **technical** limits that should prevent me from doing what I'm doing?